# How to limit figure captions to one only line

Tags: floats, captions, line

I am having trouble fitting the captions to one only line. The code I am using is the standard following:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/inicio.PNG}
\caption This caption is not ok...
\end{figure}
```

The result is this.

[image]

I would like the caption to fit in one line or, at least, to not cut the words.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Simply add a pair of braces, like this: `\caption{This caption is not ok...}`. Without them the argument of \caption is just the first letter, and the rest is just some extra stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As u/Bernard said, I just need to add brackets so that the argument of \caption is not just the first letter.

It should go like this:

`\caption{This caption is not ok...}`